# Apache Cordova Java 15 gradle-2.13-all Error

Tags: cordova, gradle

I am trying to build Apache Cordova using Visual Studio 2017

Here is the Gradle version:gradle-2.13-all

I am using Java 15 .

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Could not determine java version from '15.0.1'.

Comment: I downgraded to Java 8 and this error is resolved but I get this new error now1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Failed to read key andriod-key from store "C:\dev\jd-release-key.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded  the Java version to Java 8 and the error got resolved.